# Latest membership groups in claims with AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have couple of applications. I will call them application-1 and application-2 in the question. My applications use asp.net core 2.2.

I register user using B2C custom policies like in this example
[Azure B2C custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications) . I've added a REST API claim exchange to get user groups from the B2C. Just like this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom). I retrieve the user groups in an azure function by calling memberOf in graph api.

When user completes the registration and enters first time in the system,they are redirected to application-1. They don't have any groups assigned to them in B2C. Then in the application-1 they have option to select which group they want to join. Once they select which group they want to join, I update the B2C.

If I use refresh token provided in the documentation located at [Microsoft B2C reference OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) and access id_token from the response I don't find groups in the claims. I decoded the token for which I have used SecurityTokenHandler class.

Also My application-1 has a link to application-2 which is also part of this B2C single sign on. When user clicks the link in application-1 they are redirected into application-2 . But the id_token doesn't find latest group information which user had assigned to themselves in the application-1.

Is there anyway to make sure the id_token carries latest group information in claims?

I'm still trying to understand B2C / Single sign . Please fill free to correct my terminologies if I've used wrong terms.

Comment: Can you make sure that if  the user is in a group (with Microsoft Graph API) after the application-1 process has been completed?

Comment: I checked it multiple times . I used postman to query as well . I get instant result. One thing I'm curious about is could different client id and secrets give different results? App-1 has a backend service which checks if assignment of group was completed. Azure function has different client id and secret. Can it cause this problem?

Comment: Does App2 auth the user through the same policy as App1 did? We might be caching the result if so. Try a duplicate policy with a different policy name for App2.